# PHP: Passing an array through multiple functions

Tags: php, arrays, function, parameter-passing

Is this code possible?

A stupid question but I am having a problem understanding this.
Assuming `$product_quality[$i]` and `$saleprice[$i]` are already populated with values.
Passing an array to a function without specifying its key.

Please just follow the `$product_value[$i]` or `$player_value`

```
for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{

$product_value[$i]=($product_quality[$i]/$saleprice[$i]); 

}


$trial_x=find_four($product_value);



function find_four($player_value)
{

$trial_x=2;
$h=5;
$slope=1;

  while(abs($h)>0.01){

   $delta_y=total_value($player_value, $trial_x+0.01)-total_value($player_value, $trial_x)
   $slope=100*$delta_y;
   $h=-(total_value($player_value, $trial_x)-4)/$slope;
   $trial_x=$trial_x+$h;
  }

 return ($trial_x);
}


function total_value($player_value, $x)
{

 $total_value=0;

  for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
  {

   $total_value+=Cum_Norm($x,$player_value[$i],$sd[$i]);
  }

return($total_value);
}


function Cum_Norm($x, $mean, $sd)
{
echo $x."****1****<br/><hr/>";
echo $mean."Should be empty?***2****<br/><hr/>";
echo $sd."*****3*****<br/><hr/>";
$z=($x-$mean)/$sd;
echo $z."*****4*****<br/><hr/>";

$b1=0.31938;
$b2=-0.35656;
$b3=1.78148;
$b4=-1.82126;
$b5=1.33027;
$c=0.3989423;

if ($z>=0)
{
   $t=1/(1+0.2316419*$z);
   echo $t."*****5*****<br/><hr/>";
   return (1.0 - $c * exp( -$z * $z / 2 ) * $t * ( $t *( $t * ( $t * ( $t * $b5 + $b4 ) + $b3 ) + $b2 ) + $b1 ));  
}

else
{
$t=1/(1-0.2316419*$z); 
echo $t."*****5*****<br/><hr/>";  
return ($c * exp( -$z * $z / 2 ) * $t * ( $t *( $t * ( $t * ( $t * $b5 + $b4 ) + $b3 ) + $b2 ) + $b1 ));  
}
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *whole array* `$product_value` is passed as a full array to the function `find_four()`.  However, `find_four()` does not directly make use of the values in the `$product_value` array. Instead, the complete array is passed next to the function `total_value()`.

`total_value()` receives the *whole array* (called `$player_value` in scope of the function `find_four()`) and performs calculations using all elements of the array.  `total_value()` receives the array and uses its elements inside a `for` loop.

It isn't totally clear from your question what you don't understand, but it seems to be the part about passing a whole array rather than individual values.  An array can be passed to a function, and indeed all the built-in PHP `array_*()` functions depend on that behavior.

By default, PHP passes arrays between functions by value rather than by reference, so the function receives a *copy* of the original array rather than the original. Any modifications the function makes to the array passed in are local modifications only.

Arrays (like any values) can be passed by reference as in `function_call(&$array)`, so modifications inside `function_call()` will modify the original array passed to it.  Certain built-ins like [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) accept an array reference, therefore acting on the original array passed in without needing to return it and assign it back to a variable.

```
$input_array = array(1,2,3,4,5);

// Pass the whole array to a function (by value)
function showArray($input_array) {
  print_r($input_array);
}

showArray($input_array);
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
```

Comment: Thank you I was aware this question might be quite difficult to comprehend what I was looking for but you managed to answer my concerns. I was wondering if by passing just the $product_value array to a function, would the function have access to all values stored in the array ie $product_value[$i] where $i is between 0 and 4 inclusive.